# Dependency Strategy when using different dependency depending on parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Having this interface :

```
public interface FileManager {
    string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file);
    string UploadFile(Uri uri);
}
```

my implementation will looks like :

```
public class FileManagerAzure : FileManager {
    private FileParser parser;
    FileManagerAzure(FileParser parser){
        this.parser = parser; // Can this be a constructor injection??
    }

    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        return parser.Parse(file); // Should I Inject the parser here depending on type ??
    }
    public string UploadFile(Uri uri) {
        return parser.Parse(uri);
    }
}
```

this have a dependency on FileParser which looks like following :

```
public interface FileParser {
    string Parse(object source)
}
```

and ideally I would like to have some parsers implementations (this doesn't work of course) :

```
public class FileParserHttpPostedFileBase : FileParser {
    string Parse(HttpPostedFileBase source) {
        return file.FileName;
    }
}

public class FileParserUri : FileParser {
    string Parse(Uri source) {
        return Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

1. Is there anyway to create the concrete parser dependency depending on the parameter passed to `UploadFile()` ? this have to be a setter injection ? Is this good, or are any other strategy I can follow ?
2. I have to make my `FileParser` interface receive an object as source. This doesn't sound like it should since I have a limited set allowed input types, certainly not `object`. In this case `HttpPostedFileBase` and `Uri`. How can I limit the scope for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the dependencies via the constructor. That's the way I'd choose whenever possible. That means you can't use an IoC container for instantiation, though. You can use an abstract factory pattern to encapsulate the decision making of what concrete parser to inject, and have an IoC container inject the concrete factory into the calling class(es).

Seems like overkill, though. Since your `FileManager` interface exposes methods for both argument types why not inject both parser types? I'd make the `FileParser` type generic for that, so you don't need a new interface for every new parser.

```
public interface FileParser<T>
{
    string Parse(T value);
}

public class UriParser : FileParser<Uri>
{
    string Parse(Uri value)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

You could implement the `FileManagerAzure` like this then:

```
public class FileManagerAzure : FileManager {
    private FileParser<Uri> uriParser;
    private FileParser<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFileParser;
    FileManagerAzure(FileParser<Uri> uriParser, FileParser<HttpPostedFileBase> postedFileParser){
        this.uriParser = uriParser;
        this.postedFileParser = postedFileParser;
    }

    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        return this.postedFileParser.Parse(file);
    }
    public string UploadFile(Uri uri) {
        return this.uriParser.Parse(uri);
    }
}
```

This implementation can be instantiated by an IoC container no problem too.

Comment: I see, injecting all parsers on contructor is not bad then. Can you light me in how can I make the FileParser generic ?

Comment: Well, if or once you need a load of different parser implementations, it's time to think about a more sophisticated strategy, but for now this is fine. As to the generic interface, see my edit.

Comment: @bstenzel: Wow, I just read your answer now after posting my own and it seems we're saying exactly the same. +1

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use generic typing:

```
public interface FileParser<T> {
    string Parse(T source)
}
```

This way you can easily have multiple implementations as follows:

```
public class FileParserHttpPostedFileBase : FileParser<HttpPostedFileBase> {
    public string Parse(HttpPostedFileBase source) {
        return file.FileName;
    }
}

public class FileParserUri : FileParser<Uri> {
    public string Parse(Uri source) {
        return Uri.ToString();
    }
}
```

And this way you remove the ambiguity in your design because now it becomes clear what to inject into the constructor:

```
public class FileManagerAzure : FileManager {
    private FileParser<HttpPostedFileBase> httpParser;
    private FileParser<Uri> uriParser;
    FileManagerAzure(FileParser<HttpPostedFileBase> httpParser, 
        FileParser<Uri> uriParser){
        this.httpParser = httpParser;
        this.uriParser = uriParser;
    }

    public string UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) {
        return httpParser.Parse(file);
    }
    public string UploadFile(Uri uri) {
        return uriParser.Parse(uri);
    }
}
```

However, if the `FileManagerAzure` only delegates to its dependencies like this, you should question whether the `FileManager` abstraction has any use. A consumer of the `FileManager` could depend directly on one of the `FileParser<T>` abstractions. And if the `FileParser<T>` only has that one line of code, we could even argue that you might even want to do without that abstraction (however, as always: your mileage may vary).